# Add function in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to incorporate [this](https://gist.github.com/tylerapplebaum/dc527a3bd875f11871e2) function to my script but it shows me errors If I add any other code before this function as seen below. I enclosed the parameter in {} and the error no longer shows but it messes up my output since the parameters are no longer being defined. I have other code that needs to run and before this part of the script executes. You can see adding any other code before this function causes errors.

So I don't know how to include this part of the script with my other code and have it work. Any Help?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using pictures for code. It makes it impossible to copy it.

Comment: What you need to do is just place that code in a function.

Comment: Take the `Get-TraceRoute` code and convert it into a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decorators and parameters need to be placed at the top of a script.

So, your parameter declaration (the `[CmdletBinding]` to then end of the `param()` block) should be at the top of the script.  Then you can include that other function in it's entirety.  For instance, it would look like...

```
 [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias("s")]
    [IPAddress]$DNSServer = $null,

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [Alias("f")]
    [String]$Filename = "Traceroute_$Target"

    )#end of your original param block

Function Get-TraceRoute{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [String]$Target,
#. omitting 230 lines.#

$PerTraceArr | Format-Table -Autosize
}#end of Get-TraceRoute
```

You would then end the script like so:

```
}#end of Get-TraceRoute

Get-TraceRoute -Target $ip #or whichever params you want to pass in to your `.ps1` file.
```

Comment: you and me posted the exact same thing lol. At the exact same time

Comment: yeah putting it at the top seems to be working.. I will test everything and confirm in 2 mins

Answer (score 7):

Place the script into a function. You just surround the code in a function.

```
Function Get-Traceroute{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [String]$Target,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Alias("c")]
        [ValidateRange(5,100)]
        [int]$PingCycles = 10, #Default to 10 pings per hop; minimum of 5, maximum of 100

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Alias("b")]
        [ValidateRange(32,1000)]
        [int]$BufLen = 32, #Default to 32 bytes of data in the ICMP packet, maximum of 1000 bytes

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Alias("s")]
        [IPAddress]$DNSServer = $Null,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Alias("f")]
        [String]$Filename = "Traceroute_$Target"

    )
    Function script:Set-Variables {
    ...more code here...
}
```

Then you can just call the function `Get-TraceRoute -Target 8.8.8.8`

Comment: i will test everything and confirm. 5 mins please :)

Comment: Great minds think exactly alike at the exact same time :)